# How to get data of unknown/flexible or dynamic key via GSON?

Tags: json, gson

We have JSON data as below and the dynamic key or field names (language.typeOfLesson.completed_at) are different for every user.

How could we get data of unknown/flexible or dynamic field names (language.typeOfLesson.completed_at) via GSON?

If we can not get data of unknown field names via GSON, are there any ways to get/print all field names and each data via GSON?

```
    [
       {
          "email":"email1@gmail.com",
          "confirmed_at":"2017-12-03T18:34:32.000Z",
          "activated":true
       },
       {
          "email":"email3@gmail.com",
          "confirmed_at":"2017-10-03T18:34:32.000Z",
          "activated":true,
          "python.sql_injection.completed_at":"2018-01-24T22:05:25.000Z"
       },      
       {  
          "email":"email2@gmail.com",
          "confirmed_at":"2017-11-03T18:34:32.000Z",
          "activated":true,
          "java.privileged_interface_exposure.completed_at":"2018-01-19T19:45:44.000Z",
          "java.horizontal_privilege_escalation.completed_at":"2018-01-19T19:49:19.000Z"
       },
       {
          "email":"email5@gmail.com",
          "confirmed_at":"2017-08-03T18:34:32.000Z",
          "activated":true,
          "python.sql_injection.completed_at":"2018-01-24T22:05:25.000Z",
          "java.horizontal_privilege_escalation.completed_at":"2018-01-19T19:49:19.000Z",
          "android.sql_injection.completed_at":"2018-01-24T22:05:25.000Z"
       }
    ]
```

```
User.java
class User {
   String email;
   String confirmed_at;
   boolean activated;

   // Example: 
   // <java.sql_injection, 2018-01-24T22:05:25.000Z>
   // <java.horizontal_privilege_escalation, 2018-01-19T19:49:19.000Z>
   Map<String, String> completedLessons; // How to get date of courses/lessons completed by user?
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating a custom [TypeAdapter](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html), for example:

```java
public class UserTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<User> {
    // Call nullSafe() to make it handle null Users on its own
    public static final TypeAdapter<User> INSTANCE = new UserTypeAdapter().nullSafe();
    
    private UserTypeAdapter() { }
    
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, User value) throws IOException {
        // You will have to implement this in case you are
        // also writing JSON data
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    @Override
    public User read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        Map<String, String> completedLessons = new HashMap<>();
        
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.nextName();
            switch (name) {
                case "email":
                    user.email = in.nextString();
                    break;
                case "confirmed_at":
                    user.confirmed_at = in.nextString();
                    break;
                case "activated":
                    user.activated = in.nextBoolean();
                    break;
                // Treat every other name as lesson
                default:
                    completedLessons.put(name, in.nextString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        in.endObject();
        
        user.completedLessons = completedLessons;
        return user;
    }
}
```

You then use a GsonBuilder on which you [register](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.Object)) that adapter and create the Gson instance:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, UserTypeAdapter.INSTANCE)
    .create();
```

Note: You can also parse the dates (instead of leaving them as String). To do so you can use a custom [TypeAdapterFactory](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which creates the TypeAdapter shown above but allows it to delegate to the date adapter.